# Adding winusb dll to codeblocks

Tags: c++, dll, codeblocks, winusb

I want cod user-mode winusb project, but when I want to use it in codeblocks project for example with `WinUsb_Initialize` function I have error `undefined reference`.

How can I link winusb.dll to codeblock project to work?

I'm using codeblock 20.03 with mingw32 9.2

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve] - specifically what function as you calling that gives `undefined reference` and what is the exact __complete__ error message.  Also which toolchain are you using?

Comment: did you add `-lwinusb` to the link flags?